# MySQL "less than" not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, datetime-format

I've this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `t_activities` 
WHERE  `uid` =2
AND  `del` =0
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `time` ) < 1327518485
ORDER BY  `id` DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

The image below is what is returned.
[image]

The time `1327518485` is actually converted from the datetime string `'2012-01-25 20:08:05'` using php `strtotime('2012-01-25 20:08:05')`.

With the query, I'm expecting to load files which were inserted prior to `'2012-01-25 20:08:05'` or `1327518485`; but the result still has files inserted after it.

Is there something wrong with the way I handled the conditioning at the query?

Comment: Are you sure UNIX_TIMESTAMP(  `time` ) returning exact timestamp you have in database?

Comment: What type is the `time` column?

Comment: Question, are both the webserver you are running PHP and the MySQL server on the same machine? This could be a case of differing system clocks if they are not.

Comment: Why would you convert the date to timestamp in the first place? You have datetime in the database, you get the datetime in PHP. You can use the two without converting to timestamp.

Comment: Have a look at your locales setup (system, database, etc). Maybe there is some timezone offset that you are not taking into account.

Comment: I inserted the values as mysql using "NOW()". Field type for time is `datetime`.

Comment: Or differing timezone offsets.  How much after are they showing?

Comment: What format is `'time'`? If it is a mysql TIMESTAMP, it gets converted to your timezone, while UNIX_TIMESTAMP is UTC?

Comment: @crush it's on the same machine. I'm in locahost using XAMPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do the timestamp conversion. You can just do:

```
`time` < '2012-01-25 20:08:05'
```

You may have timezone issues with the timestamp.

Comment: Ok. I used the conversion because I don't know how to generate the date format `2012-01-25 20:08:05` in php.

Comment: Most likely you're right about the time zone issues, MySQL converts the date entered (assumed local time) to UTC and the comparison is comparing local time to that.

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);` - that's how.

Comment: @ptamzz, if you don't know how to format a date, look at [PHP date() fn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I guess the conversion is where the problem was. It works fine when I used it without converting to the UNIX format. Even though it's working that way, I'm still wondering why was I having a problem when I was using `strtotime()`.

Answer (score 1):

In order for

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`time`) < 1327518485
```

to work properly, 'time' must be a column of type `timestamp`. If 'time' is a `date` or `datetime` column, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` causes a time zone conversion.

When inserting the value into the 'time' column as a `timestamp`, use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` instead of `NOW()` to store the current time value independent of the current time zone.